# TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null at Class.run ~/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve.js:22:61

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I keep getting this error on my prod box, and all the searching i have done indicate that this error is caused by missing angular.json file, but i am NOT missing that file in the root of my project!!!

When i run npm start, npm build, npm test, etc i get back this same exact error.

When i cloned the repo onto my prod box i went into the folder and then did "npm install" which should have installed all the dependancies, but i cant get this error to go away on my prod box and i am unsure what is different from prod to dev server that would cause this error.

```
dtadmin@my-prod-server:~/portal$ npm test

> ng-crud-table@0.0.0 test /home/portal
> ng test

As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

Cannot read property 'config' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
    at /home/portal/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/test.js:12:77
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Class.run (/home/portal/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/test.js:10:16)
    at Class.run (/home/portal/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/test.js:29:25)
    at Class.<anonymous> (/home/portal/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Here is my test.js file as requested:

```
"use strict";
var Task = require('../ember-cli/lib/models/task');
var path = require('path');
var require_project_module_1 = require('../utilities/require-project-module');
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = Task.extend({
    run: function (options) {
        var _this = this;
        var projectRoot = this.project.root;
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            var karma = require_project_module_1.requireDependency(projectRoot, 'karma');
            var karmaConfig = path.join(projectRoot, _this.project.ngConfig.config.test.karma.config);
            var karmaOptions = Object.assign({}, options);
            // Convert browsers from a string to an array
            if (options.browsers) {
                karmaOptions.browsers = options.browsers.split(',');
            }
            karmaOptions.angularCli = {
                codeCoverage: options.codeCoverage,
                sourcemap: options.sourcemap,
                progress: options.progress
            };
            // Assign additional karmaConfig options to the local ngapp config
            karmaOptions.configFile = karmaConfig;
            // :shipit:
            var karmaServer = new karma.Server(karmaOptions, resolve);
            karmaServer.start();
        });
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=/Users/hans/Sources/angular-cli/packages/angular-cli/tasks/test.js.map
```

Comment: Please show content of /home/portal/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/test.js, you have probably errors inside. I think, that you can also delete node_modules folder, clear npm cache and reinstall modules by npm i

Comment: all set just added it to my original post, all of these files are saved through git so when i clone it should be exact copy.

Comment: did you run npm i after cloning repo?

Comment: yes, also tried deleting the entire repo and then cloning it again.

Comment: maybe try upgrade angular-cli?

Comment: that did not work, and now i am getting the same error on my dev machine which i did not touch... ugh...

Answer (score 0):

Somehow this got added into my package.json file:

```
"angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.28.3",
```

my friend thinks a script might have done this inadvertently, but that is what was causing the error.